# Unable to install previous versions from Ubuntu updates repository in 18.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, repository

I have a requirement where I get current Ubuntu packages with security updates available and store them in the file with format =.
For Eg : some days back, I got a security update in package named "file" and latest version at that point of time was "1:5.32-2ubuntu0.3". 
When one of my users tried to install this package after doing apt-get update, he got an error that this package is not found on repo. Instead, its upgrade is available with version "1:5.32-2ubuntu0.4".
I also looked on repo's Packages.gz file and found that this version was not present.
Where can I find the previous package? Is there any mirror which contains all the previous packages that once came into official repo?
Any help in this direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you talking about? If the distro has reached its EOL (End of Life) old packages may be discarded - the repositories will vanish. So to get an answer, you should name the version and the package you couldn't  update. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1239415/edit) your question and fill in the missing information

Comment: I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have named the package and version in question's description. Package name is file and version is 1:5.32-2ubuntu0.3, which has recently been updated.

Comment: I have edited the question to include distro version. Thanks for pointing that out.